# PHP socket programming transferred image is corrupted

Tags: php, sockets

I have a `PHP` **socket client** which transfer a `image (BMP)` to the **socket server**

```
$host="127.0.0.1" ;
$port=8000;
$timeout=30;
$socket=fsockopen($host,$port,$errnum,$errstr,$timeout) ;


$bmp=file_get_contents("C:/Image.bmp");
$bytesWritten = fwrite($socket, $bmp);
fclose($socket);
```

The transferred image is **always corrupted and halfly** streamed and giving the error message

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
```

im transferring from localhost to localhost ;) and i have a **ASP.NET** app which does the same thing in milliseconds ! so why not **PHP**? why it takes long time ?

i think there is some thing to do with `file_get_contents` which creates a large `BLOB` behalf of that is there a way to use a **FileStream** in `PHP` ?

any idea how to transfer the file without corrupting ?

Comment: What kind of a link are you doing this transfer on? Transferring a 100meg file over a 56k dialup line is going to take more than 60 seconds...

Comment: I imagine it's corrupted because it hasn't completed transfer. Sixty seconds is a long time unless you're on dial-up. Are you sure the socket connection isn't failing? If not, does it just not have enough time/bandwidth to finish?

Comment: im transferring from localhost to localhost ;) and i have a ASP.NET app which does the same thing in milliseconds ! so why not PHP?

Comment: You should show how you opened the `$socket` in your code above.

Comment: `file_get_contents` returns a string which is probably not what you want.

Comment: yes thats the thing.. i think what i need is a `FileStream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_get_contents` returns a string. I think you want to use `fread` instead.

Example:

```
$filename = "c:\\files\\somepic.gif";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: im transferring from `localhost` to `localhost` ;) and i have a `ASP.NET` app which does the same thing in milliseconds ! so why not `PHP`?

Comment: Wow, that is a long time then! How big is this bitmap file?

Comment: i think there is some thing to do with `file_get_contents` which creates a large `BLOB` behalf of that is there a way to use a **FileStream** in `PHP` ?

Comment: @Sudantha - I updated the code with `fread` instead of `file_get_contents`.

Comment: i wrote the `$contents` to the socket looks like the same result ! :'(

Comment: @Sudantha - what is running on port 8000? Web server?

Comment: I suspect you are running a webserver. I have to head out, but if you are running a webserver then that makes this much more complicated. You'd have to use something like [cURL](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) support in PHP. [Example #2 Uploading file](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) is probably want you want. Good luck!

Comment: thaks jwr for help `8000` runs a socket server when coded my be in C# ... ASP.NET clients and transfer without no hassle ! prob is `PHP` !